# Polymer: change property of different instances of an element

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm trying to create a method/function **inside** my polymer element that allows me to change a property to all instances except the one clicked/tapped.

Being more specific, when I click on an instance of the element, I want to change a CSS property of every other instances of it.

[Image exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXiEz.png)

Thanks!

Comment: We can't help you unless you provide us with your code.

Comment: Ok... I'll post it if it's necessary but I was looking for a general solution. I just wanted to know if there's a possibility to target changes to every instance of an element except on clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with [polymer-signals](http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/communication.html#using-ltpolymer-signalsgt). Just have each window listen for a signal event and update itself accordingly.